# ParallelPeriod issues when time is not on axis

Tags: ssas, mdx, olap

What's wrong with the calculated member [Amount LM] (=amount last month) in this query? It seems to work if I specify the time on rows but fails if I don't, even though I have a date in the where clause.

```sql
WITH

MEMBER [Amount LM] as
    (
        [Measures].[Amount],

        ParallelPeriod (
            [Date].[Year - Quarter - Month - Date - Hierarchy].[Year and Month],
            1,
            [Date].[Year - Quarter - Month - Date - Hierarchy].CurrentMember
        )
    )


SELECT 
   {[Amount LM], [Measures].[Amount]} ON  COLUMNS,

[Measure Types].[Name].&[22] --not related to [Measures].[Amount]; Used as a measure switch in the real case but adjusted here for simplicity
-- comment out the next line to fail
* [Date].[Year - Quarter - Month - Date - Hierarchy].[Year and Month] 

ON rows


FROM [Cube]
WHERE [Date].[Year Number].&[2019]
;
```

Result in the working case:

```
                           Amount LM  |  Amount
    Costs  |    Jan 2019  | (null)    |  109600
    Costs  |    Feb 2019  | 109600    |  218300.5
    Costs  |    Mar 2019  | 218300.5  |  392250
    Costs  |    Apr 2019  | 392250    |  206800
    Costs  |    May 2019  | 206800    |  174700
    Costs  |    Jun 2019  | 174700    |  298400
    Costs  |    Jul 2019  | 298400    |  264550
    Costs  |    Aug 2019  | 264550    |  424100
    Costs  |    Sep 2019  | 424100    |  129650
    Costs  |    Oct 2019  | 129650    |  330050
    Costs  |    Nov 2019  | 330050    |  (null)
    Costs  |    Dec 2019  | (null)    |  (null)
```

Without the

```
* [Date].[Year - Quarter - Month - Date - Hierarchy].[Year and Month]
```

part, Amount LM ist NULL

```
          |Amount LM| Amount
    Costs | (null)  | 2548400.5
```

Comment: Does the below helps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no issue with your calculation. To understand the Null you need to know

1. How ParallelPeriod works
2. How "CurrentMember" on a UserHierarchy works

When you have

> "[Date].[Year - Quarter - Month - Date - Hierarchy].[Year and Month]"

in your row axis

> "[Date].[Year - Quarter - Month - Date - Hierarchy].CurrentMember"

The above ".currentmember" expression returns the current member of the USER HIERARCHY "[Year - Quarter - Month - Date - Hierarchy]". The PARALLEL PERIOD function then tries to find the cousin member with respect to LEVEL "[Year and Month]".

When you remove the user hierarchy from rows , the currentmember returns 2019, which is a member of LEVEL "YEAR Number" hence the parallel period cannot find a cousin with respect to LEVEL "[Year and Month]"(since the passed currentmember is above the LEVEL specified). To check replace the year in the where with a month member(and no date on rows) it will work. To solve the issue , you need to provide an alternate logic incase if a higher level member is passed or other edge cases use the script below it will return 100 in any edge case .

```
WITH

MEMBER [Amount LM] as
case when [Date].[Year - Quarter - Month - Date - Hierarchy].CurrentMember.level.name <>"Year and Month" then 100
else 
(
    [Measures].[Amount],

    ParallelPeriod (
        [Date].[Year - Quarter - Month - Date - Hierarchy].[Year and Month],
        1,
        [Date].[Year - Quarter - Month - Date - Hierarchy].CurrentMember
    )
)
end
```

Below is an example of your problem on Adventure works.
I have added two columns to check what ParallelPeriod and .currentmember are return

```
WITH
MEMBER [Amount LM] as
(
    [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount],
    ParallelPeriod ([Date].[Calendar].[Month],1,[Date].[Calendar].currentmember)
)

MEMBER [Amount LM_ParallelPeriodName] as
(
    ParallelPeriod ([Date].[Calendar].[Month],1,[Date].[Calendar].currentmember).name
)

MEMBER [Amount LM_CalendarCurrentmember] as
(
    [Date].[Calendar].currentmember.name
)

SELECT 
{[Amount LM], [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount],[Amount LM_ParallelPeriodName],[Amount LM_CalendarCurrentmember]} ON  COLUMNS,
[Product].[Category].&[1] * [Date].[Calendar].[Month]
ON rows
from [Adventure Works]
WHERE [Date].[Calendar Year].&[2013]
```

Result 
[image: FirstResult]

Now Lets comment the

> "[Date].[Calendar].[Month]"

```
WITH
MEMBER [Amount LM] as
(
    [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount],
    ParallelPeriod ([Date].[Calendar].[Month],1,[Date].[Calendar].currentmember)
)

MEMBER [Amount LM_ParallelPeriodName] as
(
    ParallelPeriod ([Date].[Calendar].[Month],1,[Date].[Calendar].currentmember).name
)

MEMBER [Amount LM_CalendarCurrentmember] as
(
    [Date].[Calendar].currentmember.name
)

SELECT 
{[Amount LM], [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount],[Amount LM_ParallelPeriodName],[Amount LM_CalendarCurrentmember]} ON  COLUMNS,
[Product].[Category].&[1] --* [Date].[Calendar].[Month]
ON rows
from [Adventure Works]
WHERE [Date].[Calendar Year].&[2013]
```

Result 
[image: Result2]
 Notice the Null returned by ParallelPeriod, Now lets replace the Year in where from Month. This enables paralellperiod to return something useful

```
WITH
MEMBER [Amount LM] as
(
    [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount],
    ParallelPeriod ([Date].[Calendar].[Month],1,[Date].[Calendar].currentmember)
)

MEMBER [Amount LM_ParallelPeriodName] as
(
    ParallelPeriod ([Date].[Calendar].[Month],1,[Date].[Calendar].currentmember).name
)

MEMBER [Amount LM_CalendarCurrentmember] as
(
    [Date].[Calendar].currentmember.name
)

SELECT 
{[Amount LM], [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount],[Amount LM_ParallelPeriodName],[Amount LM_CalendarCurrentmember]} ON  COLUMNS,
[Product].[Category].&[1] * [Date].[Calendar].[Month]
ON rows
from [Adventure Works]
WHERE [Date].[Month Name].[September 2013]
```

Result 
[image]

Comment: I think I got it now. Thanks